# How can I better vertical-align images>text?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

With text alongside a thumbnail, my line-height of 1.6 of course affects the vertical align of my images>text... the text is lower than the top of the image - I assume by about 8px.

Other than adding a negative margin-top to the paragraph is there a workaround for this?

```
              ----------------------------------------
```

UPDATE: with a new day my brain-fade has hopefully passed, and I regret asking this question. If it hadn't received answers, I'd have deleted - but will now leave as-is and suggest it be ignored.

I think that amid the frustrations of trying (and being unable) to get stuff as I want, I posted in hope rather than serious expectation.

Commonsense suggests that with line-height greater than 1, vertical alignment won't be perfect because of the additional space (above and below the characters) in the text.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: do `vertical-align: middle;` on the image

Comment: @Mohammad Usman ...thanks. I haven't included code, because this seems such a basic issue that code (of which there's of course a variety of ways to position text alongside an image) didn't seem necessary.

Comment: @N. Ivanov... thanks. But how will that align the top of the image with the top of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Use of `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
   This is test
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The desired alignment is the top of the image with the top of the text.